# Running bundle exec linguist --breakdown fails

Tags: github-linguist

When I run `bundle exec linguist --breakdown` on the root directory, I get the following error:

> No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
>   /Users/George/linguist/lib/linguist/samples.json (Errno::ENOENT)

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

By executing `bundle exec rake samples` in the linguist directory.

This step is required to generate the `samples.json` file which contains condensed information on [sample files](https://github.com/github/linguist/tree/master/samples) for [the Bayesian classifier](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/71032cd2528d599d6563640c60f13ad865f17364/lib/linguist/classifier.rb).